# Cannot run type in anything in interactive session for Apache Airflow Scheduler

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

#### Issue description

I have an issue with writing anything in the interactive session for the docker container, which is responsible for running the scheduler of Apache Airflow.

Firstly I run:

```
 docker container exec --tty apacheairflow-airflow-scheduler-1 /bin/bash
```

After executing it, it looks like I entered the interactive session which shows the screen below:
[image]

but I cannot type in anything there.

#### Question

Do you know what could be the reason for this issue? If you need anything more to know in advance, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start an interactive shell inside a Docker Container, you need to add the argument `--interactive` (or `-i`):

```bash
docker container exec -it apacheairflow-airflow-scheduler-1 /bin/bash
```